# Regarding Azure ML Managed Online Endpoints

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Azure Log Analytics and Application Insights aren't supported when using network isolation with a deployment. To see the logs for the deployment, which command I need to use.

Can you please help with the availability of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the az ml online-deployment get_logs command instead. Log Analytics support will be partial at GA. Application Insights support is not included yet.